# CASpringAnimation for UIView frame

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, caanimation

I am using this code to animate a view with spring animation but it doesn't seem to be doing that. View snaps to the frame without any "spring"animation.

***BEFORE*** you suggest to do it with:

`UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.65, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 3.0, options: .curveEaseOut , animations: {...}`

I just want to tell you that my view uses cornerRadius so I cannot animate cornerRadius with the above!

```
 magnifyView (layer: CALayer, size: CGSize) {

     let oldBounds = layer.bounds
        var newBounds = oldBounds
        newBounds.size = size

        let animateFrame = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")

        animateFrame.fromValue = NSValue(cgRect: oldBounds)
        animateFrame.toValue = NSValue(cgRect: newBounds)
        animateFrame.damping = 0.65
        animateFrame.initialVelocity = 3.0
        animateFrame.duration = animateFrame.settlingDuration


            layer.add(animateFrame, forKey: "transform.scale")
             layer.bounds = newBounds

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your animation is wrong. You set the key path to transform.scale, which would be a CGFloat that causes the whole view to change size.

Then you plug in fromValue and toValue NSValues that are CGRects. I suspect you'll get an error in the console when you run that code.

If you want to animate the frame, animate the frame. (not bounds, frame.) use

```
let oldFrame = layer.frame
```

...

```
let animateFrame = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "frame")
```

...

```
animateFrame.fromValue = NSValue(cgRect: oldFrame)
animateFrame.toValue = NSValue(cgRect: newFrame)
```

...

```
layer.frame = newFrame
```

### EDIT:

It's certainly easier to do this using UIView animations as mentioned at the beginning of your question. Try code like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var isLarge: Bool = false
  @IBOutlet weak var roundLabel: UILabel!

  @IBAction func handleResizeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    isLarge = !isLarge
    let size: CGFloat = isLarge ? 1.5 : 1.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.65, delay: 0, 
      usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, 
      initialSpringVelocity: 3.0, 
      options: .curveEaseOut, 
      animations: {
        self.roundLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: size, y: size)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: no errors in my console. changing bounds to frame makes no difference to my animation (still snaps instead of spring)

Comment: Note that you also need to change the keyPath you use to create the animation.

Comment: If you're using auto-layout then changing the frame won't work as expected. The constraints on your view will take over and change the frame to the final value, overriding the animation. You should use UIView animation and animate constraints on the x and 7 positions of your view.

Comment: You say "I just want to tell you that my view uses cornerRadius so I cannot animate cornerRadius with the above!" I don't know what that means. The code you posted does not change the cornerRadius of your view, so I'm not sure what you mean. You can use UIView animation to animate a view with a non-zero corner radius and it works just fine.

Comment: no you are right. This is not the finished code. I just wanted to make it clear that I want to animate the cornerRadius AS WELL as the frame...

Comment: No there is no auto layout used. And YES I did change the keyPath to "frame"

Comment: Did you explicitly turn off the "use auto-layout" checkbox for your storyboard/XIB? If you did not do that then you **are** using auto-layout even though you think you're not.

Comment: makes no difference. enabled or disabled. see gif image above

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I provided tested, working code that animates the view's transform using UIVIew spring animation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133296/discussion-between-duncan-c-and-george-asda).